# Sonar as a service

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, saas

I want to run SonarQube as software as a service for my code review. In other words, I don't want a dedicated machine to host sonar for me.

Is there any cloud service available to do so?
Also, I want to integrate it with my build definition in VSTS and generate report. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be looking for [SonarCloud](https://about.sonarcloud.io/), which is free for open source projects, but paid for private projects.